# One email form, different recipeints

Tags: email, email-contact-form

I am building a site that lists different service providers.

On each service provider's page there is a contact form (the same form for each service provider).

The email address of each service provider (the recipient) is in the channel entry.

How can I get the email sent to each respective service provider - as well as the site owner?

I am trying to avoid using a different script for each form - and I don't want to expose the recipient's email address in the page code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Template Parsing order](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/template_engine.html), you will see that [segment variables](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/url_segments.html) are parsed before [Preload Replace Variables](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html). You can take advantage of that.

```
{if segment_2 == "foo"}
    {preload_replace:pr-recipient="contact@foo.com,"}
{if:elseif segment_2 == "bar"}
    {preload_replace:pr-recipient="sales@bar.com,"}
{/if}

    {preload_replace:pr-recipient=""}

{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="{pr-recipient}site-owner@example.com" charset="utf-8"}

    [...]

{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how the above answer would have worked, I'm really not sure I understood it. :/

However, I was able to accomplish what I wanted pretty easily with Solspace's Freeform. Also I needed custom fields which Freeform is great at doing.

Also I need to mention Solspace has ***awesome*** support.